# How to check / detect if user begun a new line in TextField / TextEditor?

Tags: swift, swiftui, newline, text-editor, detect

I want to check in my TextEditor if the user pressed the "↵" (new line) button on the phones keyboard, so I can code, that on every new line the code automatically adds a "-" at the very beginning in the new line.

I want it to be like if you press return key in Microsoft Word after you entered a "-" so it's setting a "-" sign infront, like a checklist.

I found nothing that solves my problem. I played a little bit with the ".onChange" event of the TextEditor but I didn't found any solution.

Thank you for your answers in the future :)

Like mentioned above I tried ".onChanged" action and googleing.

I want it to be like in MS Word if you add a "-" in a new line it automatically adds a "-" every new line if you press the return key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a solution in SwiftUI:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var text = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Enter text below:")
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                if newValue.last == "\n" {
                    text += "-"
                }
            }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

`"\n"` represents the "Newline" or "Line Feed" character in Swift. This character is often associated with the "Enter" or "Return" key on the keyboard. Something like this should hopefully work.

Comment: Yeah that kind of solved my problem, it's almost what I tried! Thank you!